# ket.draw() not showing |00> : Qiskit

Tags: python, quantum-computing, qiskit

`ket.draw()` must give `|00>` as result but I get:

```
Statevector([1.+0.j, 0.+0.j, 0.+0.j, 0.+0.j],
               dims=(2, 2))
```

what can I change to get the desired result?

This is my code:

```py
from qiskit import QuantumCircuit
from qiskit.quantum_info import Statevector

qc = QuantumCircuit(2)

# This calculates what the state vector of our qubits would be
# after passing through the circuit 'qc'
ket = Statevector(qc)

# The code below writes down the state vector.
# Since it's the last line in the cell, the cell will display it as output
ket.draw()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass the keyword argument `output='latex'` to the `.draw` method.

```
from qiskit import QuantumCircuit
from qiskit.quantum_info import Statevector

qc = QuantumCircuit(2)

# This calculates what the state vector of our qubits would be
# after passing through the circuit 'qc'
ket = Statevector(qc)

# The code below writes down the state vector.
# Since it's the last line in the cell, the cell will display it as output
ket.draw(output='latex')
```